# Xcode simulator with react-native takes to long

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm now running Mavericks and the latest Xcode on a mid 2009 MPB. There is no problem creating the AwesomeProject and then building with Xcode. The problem starts once the simulator comes up. I see the white Powered by React Native screen and then after it goes away it takes a very long time and finally the Packager gives me the following output:

```
Error: ENOENT, open     '/Users/SM/AwesomeProject/AwesomeProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/SM.xcuserdatad/.dat2864.046'
    at Error (native)
[3:15:07 PM] <START> request:/index.ios.bundle
[3:15:07 PM] <START> find dependencies
[3:15:10 PM] <START> find dependencies
```

This is followed by the big red screen!

Xcode also notifies me that it got disconnected from the simulator. The one warning I do see in Xcode is:

"Applications using launch screen files and targeting iOS 7.1 and earlier need to also include a launch image in an asset catalog."

How can I finally complete the Getting Started test and experience React Native?

Comment: Can you please show the red screen error?

Comment: The warning is a red herring, it does not stop the app running in the simulator.  Are you able to run the simulator okay for other applications in xcode on your 2009 mbp?

Comment: The red screen has no real message, only the following options which do not work for me on my machine:

Answer (score 0):

The red screen only has two options on it which I'm not able to use, its likely just the result of not being able to run the Simulator on my machine:

[image: The red screen options]

Bottom line I do not have enough RAM, only 4GB. After investigating it looks like I need to upgrade or get a new Mac at some point in the future. Its been a max frustrating day for me to say the least.

Here is what Activity Monitor tells me about my machine:

[image: Activity Monitor result]

That is how my machine looks without Xcode and the Simulator running! There are two upgrade options if I want to keep going now. Double my RAM and optionally get a SSD. Does anyone know if this will be enough to get the Simulator working?

I did see this link saying that adding more RAM helped:

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/120512-how-much-ram-needed-desirable-on-an-xcode-build-machine.html

UPDATE

After the upgrade to a 500GB SSD, more RAM and a clean install of Mavericks things are working swell. I highly recommend this as a way to get more life out of a older MBP. Thanks to Memory Express and the Apple Store for all the tips and sweet deals.